# How to calculate vector direction between two vectors on a grid given a single value for X and Y

Tags: c#, math, vector, geometry

I have two values on a Cartesian grid (max value is 1).

For the X point, the value is 0.5. So the vector would point straight up from (0,0) to (0, 0.5). 
For the Y point, the value is 0.5. So the vector would point to the right from (0,0) to (0.5, 0)

So, the angle between the two vector should be 135 degrees (assuming you count degrees on the grid clockwise with 0 starting at the far left).

So, given that information, how would one calculate the angle between those two vectors?

[image]

Comment: Odd, you somehow posted a "question" without actually asking one...

Comment: @maccettura Edited. I thought the title was self-explanatory.

Comment: What do you consider to be the angle if the given value is negative? If it is zero?

Comment: @RoryDaulton For my application, the value will never be zero. If the value is negative, then the vector will point down (if it's for the Y), or point left (if it's for the X).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Thanks - that's exactly what I'm looking for. If you submit an answer instead of a reply, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The usual convention is for the zero angle to be measured from the positive x-axis, increasing in the counterclockwise direction.  This is simple trigonometry.

Answer (score 1):

The if your point is (*x*,*y*), then arctan(*y*/*x*) gives you the angle from the right axis to your point in the counterclockwise direction.
Since you want the value from the left axis in the clockwise direction, try 180 -
 arctan(*y*/*x*). (Be sure you convert the arctan result to degrees!)

Comment: Beware of divide by 0.  Because of this, there usually is an actan2(x,y) function that takes the x/y ration as 2 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use [*arctangent*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan2(v=vs.110).aspx).
Then if the angle is outside the range you want, add or subtract 2pi.

Answer (score 1):

Call `u = (ux, uy)` and `v = (vx, vy)` your two vectors.

First step: find the direction of the vector "between `u` and `v`". If `u` and `v` had same norm, we could just pick their sum. So, first, normalize `u` and `v`, then add them:

```
w        = u * norm(v) + v * norm(u)
(wx, wy) = (ux * norm(v) + vx * norm(u), uy * norm(v) + vy * norm(u))
```

Then, use `atan2` to find the angle corresponding to `w`. [There are 8 different conventions to use `atan2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#East-counterclockwise,_north-clockwise_and_south-clockwise_conventions,_etc.), and you said that you wanted the west-clockwise convention:

```
angle_radians = atan2(wy, -wx)
```

Then, since you wanted to express the angle in degrees rather than in radians, convert the units:

```
angle_degrees = angle_radians * 180 / pi.
```

Testing in python:

```py
import math

ux, uy = u = (0, 0.5)
vx, vy = v = (0.6, 0)

normu = math.hypot(ux,uy)
normv = math.hypot(vx,vy)

(wx, wy) = w = (uc * normv + vc * normu for uc,vc in zip(u,v))

angle_radians = math.atan2(wy, -wx)
angle_degrees = angle_radians * 180 / math.pi

print(angle_degrees)
# 135.0
```